# How to speed up the loading of a php page

Tags: php, ajax

Hi everybody I have the following code. When I run it on a testing environment it works quite fast, but when I deploy in production it takes up to 32 seconds to load all the icons. Could be the queries the problem? Because in testing I have only few records in DB but in production 2 tables have about 9000 entries each... I really don't know how to speed up.. I put everything inside $(document).ready, put some script in the header and 3 in the footer. Or the Ajax call could make everything working slower in production?
Thank you in advance

```
<?php

ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
session_start();
include("function.php");

    // if ( (empty($_SESSION['email']) ) || (empty($_SESSION['password'])) ){
    if ( (empty($_SESSION['email'])) && ($_SESSION['flagVariable'] !== 1) ) {

        Header("location: index.php");
    }
    else {

        $conn = connessioneDB();

?>

<!--
 *
* Copyright �<?php echo date("Y"); ?>. Poste Italiane. All Rights Reserved.
* Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this software and its
* documentation for educational, research, and not-for-profit purposes,
* without fee and without a signed licensing agreement, is hereby granted,
* provided that the above copyright notice, this paragraph and in all copies,
* modifications, and distributions.
*
* Contacts for commercial licensing opportunities:
*
* Author: Daniel
* Reviewed By: Emilio
* Email: 
* Mobile: 
*
*
-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>PCMDBtool ver 2.2.0 | REPORTS</title>
        <meta name="description" content="A responsive, magazine-like website layout with a grid item animation effect when opening the content" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="grid, layout, effect, animated, responsive, magazine, template, web design" />
        <meta name="author" content="Codrops" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="DataTables/extensions/Buttons/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/font-awesome-4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
        <link href="rete/css.css?family=Fjalla+One|Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css" />
        <script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">-->
        <script src="rete/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="rete/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="zebra_form.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="DataTables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="DataTables/media/js/fnSetFilteringDelay.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="DataTables/media/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="DataTables/media/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="rete/jquery-confirm.min.css">
        <script src="rete/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="catalog.js"></script>
        <link type="text/css" href="css/base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link type="text/css" href="css/Spacetree.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jit-yc.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="js/jquery.sumoselect.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sumoselect.css">

        <style type="text/css">
            .blurred{
                -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
                -moz-filter: blur(5px);
                -o-filter: blur(5px);
                -ms-filter: blur(5px);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <button id="menu-toggle" class="menu-toggle"><span>Menu</span></button>
            <div id="theSidebar" class="sidebar">
                <?php navigationRole($_SESSION['role_id']); ?>
                <button class="close-button fa fa-fw fa-close"></button>
            </div>

            <div id="theGrid" class="main">
                <section class="grid">

                    <a class="grid__item hvr-border-fade" onclick="" href="#">
                        <h2 class="title title--preview">Servizi</h2>
                        <div class="loader"></div>
                        <span class="category"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Elenco Servizi Operativi</span>
                    </a>

                    <a class="grid__item hvr-border-fade" onclick="" href="#">
                        <h2 class="title title--preview">BC</h2>
                        <div class="loader"></div>
                        <span class="category"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Business Criticality</span>
                    </a>

                    <a class="grid__item hvr-border-fade" onclick="" href="#">
                        <h2 class="title title--preview">Apparati/Servizi</h2>
                        <div class="loader"></div>
                        <span class="category"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>Elenco Apparati / Servizi </span>
                    </a>

                    <a class="grid__item hvr-border-fade" onclick="javascript:AssetSoServ()" href="#">
                        <h2 class="title title--preview">S.O. in Servizi</h2>
                        <div class="loader"></div>
                        <span class="category"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Vista completa Sistemi Operativi in Servizi</span>
                    </a>

                    <a class="grid__item hvr-border-fade" onclick="" href="#">
                        <h2 class="title title--preview">Tripletta</h2>
                        <div class="loader"></div>
                        <span class="category"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Vista completa Tripletta</span>
                    </a>

                </section>

                <section id="content" class="content">
                    <div class="scroll-wrap">



                        <script type="text/javascript" class="init">
                            $(document).ready( function () {

                                var table = $('#REPORT_SERVIZI').DataTable( {
                                    paging: true,
                                    "processing": true,
                                    "deferLoading": 57,
                                    "deferRender": true,
                                    "scrollY": 350,
                                    "scrollX": true,
                                    "bDestroy": true,
                                    "bRetrieve": true,
                                    "ordering": false,
                                    "iDisplayLength": 100,
                                    "info":     true,
                                    "sDom":     'ltipr',
                                    "bDestroy": true
                                } );

                                $("#filterboxA").keyup(function() {
                                        table.search(this.value).draw();
                                });


                                var tables = $('#TRIPLETTA').DataTable( {
                                    "paging": false,
                                    "bFilter": false,
                                    "processing": true,
                                    "serverSide": false,
                                    "deferLoading": 57,
                                    "deferRender": true,
                                    "scrollY": 300,
                                    "scrollX": true,
                                    "info": false,
                                    "bPaginate": false,
                                    "bRetrieve": true
                                } );

                                //tables.fnStandingRedraw();


                                var tableBC = $('#BC').DataTable( {
                                    paging: true,
                                    "processing": true,
                                    "ajax": "asset_BC.php",
                                    "deferLoading": 57,
                                    "deferRender": true,
                                    "scrollY": 350,
                                    "iDisplayLength": 100,
                                    "scrollX": true,
                                    "bRetrieve": true,
                                    "bDestroy": true,
                                    "ordering": false,
                                    "info":     true,
                                    "sDom":     'ltipr',
                                    "bDestroy": true
                                } );
                                $("#filterboxE").keyup(function() {
                                        tableBC.search(this.value).draw();
                                });


                                 tableSA = $('#SA').DataTable(
                                    {
                                        paging: true,
                                        "processing": true,
                                        "ajax": "asset_SA.php",
                                        "deferLoading": 57,
                                        "deferRender": true,
                                        "scrollY": 350,
                                        "iDisplayLength": 100,
                                        "scrollX": true,
                                        "bRetrieve": true,
                                        "bDestroy": true,
                                        "ordering": true,
                                        "info":     true,
                                        "sDom":     'ltipr',

                                        "bDestroy": true,

                                    } );

                                        $("#filterboxF").keyup(function() {

                                                tableSA.search(this.value).draw();

                                        });

                                        document.getElementById('filterboxF').addEventListener('keypress', function (e)
                                        {
                                            var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);

                                            if (keycode == '13') {

                                                tableSA.rows( { search:'applied' } ).data().each(function(value, index) {
                                                    //console.log(value, index);
                                                    var array = [];

                                                    array.push(value);

                                                    //console.log(array, index);
                                                });

                                            }

                                        });

                                        //table.buttons().container().appendTo( $('#stampaXls', table.table().container() ) );

                                      tableSO = $('#SO').DataTable(
                                        {
                                            paging: true,
                                            "processing": true,
                                            "ajax": "asset_SO.php",
                                            "deferLoading": 57,
                                            "deferRender": true,
                                            "scrollY": 350,
                                            "iDisplayLength": 100,
                                            "scrollX": true,
                                            "bRetrieve": true,
                                            "bDestroy": true,
                                            "ordering": true,
                                            "info":     true,
                                            "sDom":     'ltipr',

                                            "bDestroy": true,
                                            columns:
                                            [{
                                                 title: "Operation",
                                                 class:"center" },
                                                 { title: "Nome Servizio",
                                                 class:"center" },
                                                 { title: "ID Servizio",
                                                 class:"center" },
                                                 { title: "S.O.",
                                                 class:"center" },
                                                 { title: "Patch Level",
                                                 class:"center" },
                                                 { title: "Valida Dal",
                                                 class:"center" },
                                                 { title: "N° di Apparati",
                                                 class:"center" }
                                          ]

                                        } );


                                            $("#filterboxG").keyup(function() {

                                                    tableSO.search(this.value).draw();

                                            });

                                            document.getElementById('filterboxG').addEventListener('keypress', function (e)
                                            {
                                                var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);

                                                if (keycode == '13') {

                                                    tableSO.rows( { search:'applied' } ).data().each(function(value, index) {
                                                        //console.log(value, index);
                                                        var array = [];

                                                        array.push(value);

                                                    //console.log(array, index);
                                                    });

                                                }

                                            });
                                                    // when a row is clicked, show a popup menu containing all the devices inside a Service
                                                    $('#SO tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
                                                        var data = tableSO.row( this ).data();
                                                        //alert( 'You clicked on '+data[0]+'\'s row' );

                                                        $.ajax({
                                                             type:'POST',
                                                             url:'utility3.php',
                                                                 data: { opServizio: data[0], servizio: data[1], sistOp: data[3], midware: data[4], valido_dal: data[5] },
                                                             success: function(msg) {

                                                                     $('#contextMenuIdConfApparati').fadeIn('slow');
                                                                     $('#resultApparatiList').html(msg);

                                                             },
                                                             error: function(err) {
                                                                 alert('Errore: ' + err);
                                                             }
                                                             });

                                                    } );

                                            //table.buttons().container().appendTo( $('#stampaXls', table.table().container() ) );

                                } );

                            function exportSQL(tab){
                                location.href = "exportSQL.php?tab=" + tab;
                            }


                            var path = "<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>";
                            history.pushState(null, null, path + window.location.search);
                            window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event) {
                                history.pushState(null, null, path + window.location.search);
                            });


                            function clearObscuration(liv){
                                $("#closing").fadeIn();
                                $("#" + liv).fadeOut("slow", "swing");
                            }

                            function Obscuration(a){
                                $( a ).addClass("blurred");
                                removeHref();
                            }

                            function refreshDati( a ){
                                $('#' + a ).empty();
                            }

                            function exportREPORTS(tab){
                                location.href = "exportREPORTS.php?tab=" + tab;
                            }

                            function exportREPORTS2(tab){
                                location.href = "exportREPORTS_SA.php?tab=" + tab;
                            }

                            function exportREPORTS3(tab){
                                location.href = "exportREPORTS_SO.php?tab=" + tab;
                            }

                        </script>

                        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
                        <script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
                        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="DataTables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
                        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="DataTables/media/js/fnSetFilteringDelay.js"></script>
                        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="DataTables/media/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
                        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="DataTables/media/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="DataTables/extensions/Buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>

                        <article class="content__item">
                            <h3 class="title title--fullo"> <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Report:  Report Servizi</h3>
                            <div style="background: #999; color: white; font-weight: normal; padding: 10px; width: 100%">
                                Ricerca <input type="text" id="filterboxA">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <a style="color: white" href="javascript:exportREPORTS('PCMDB_CAT.REPORTS')"><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Esporta Tutto</a>
                            </div>
                                <?php
                                echo "<table id=\"REPORT_SERVIZI\" class=\"display\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"100%\">";
                                echo "<thead>";
                                echo "<tr>\n";

                                echo "<th>Codice Iniziativa</th>\n";
                                echo "<th>Servizio Operativo</th>\n";
                                echo "<th>Owner</th>\n";
                                echo "<th>Acronimo</th>\n";
                                echo "<th>Stato</th>\n";
                                echo "<th>Piattaforma</th>\n";
                                echo "<th>Service</th>\n";
                                echo "<th>DR</th>\n";
                                echo "<th>Cert</th>\n";
                                echo "<th>Sla D</th>\n";
                                echo "<th>Sla T</th>\n";

                                echo "</tr>\n";
                                echo "</thead>\n";
                                echo "<tbody>\n";
                                $stid = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT * FROM PCMDB_CAT.V_SERVIZIO WHERE STATUS!='Da cancelare' AND NOME_SERVIZIO NOT LIKE 'Dummy%'");
                                oci_execute($stid);
                                while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {

                                    $qq = "select richiesto_dr from PCMDB_CAT.sic_servizio where id_servizio=".$row['ID_SERVIZIO'];
                                    $stid2 = oci_parse($conn, $qq);
                                    oci_execute($stid2);
                                    $row2 = oci_fetch_array($stid2, OCI_ASSOC);
                                    $DR = $row2['RICHIESTO_DR'];
                                    if ($DR != "Si") { $DR = "No"; }

                                    $ss = "select count(*) from PCMDB_CAT.V_VISTA_COMPLETA where ambiente = 'CERTIFICAZIONE' and id_servizio=".$row['ID_SERVIZIO'];
                                    $stid3 = oci_parse($conn, $ss);
                                    oci_execute($stid3);
                                    $row3 = oci_fetch_array($stid3, OCI_ASSOC);
                                    $numCert = $row3['COUNT(*)'];

                                    if ($numCert > 0) { $CERT = "SI"; } else { $CERT = "NO"; }

                                    echo "<tr>\n";

                                    echo "<td>".$row['CODICE_INIZIATIVA']."</td>\n";
                                    echo "<td>".$row['NOME_SERVIZIO']."</td>\n";
                                    echo "<td>".$row['OWNER']."</td>\n";
                                    echo "<td>".$row['ACRONIMO']."</td>\n";
                                    echo "<td>".$row['STATUS']."</td>\n";
                                    echo "<td></td>\n";
                                    echo "<td>".$row['OPERATION']."</td>\n";
                                    echo "<td>".$DR."</td>\n";
                                    echo "<td>".$CERT."</td>\n";
                                    echo "<td>".$row['SLA_D']."</td>\n";
                                    echo "<td>".$row['SLA_T']."</td>\n";


                                    echo "</tr>\n";
                                    $CERT = "";
                                }
                                echo "</tbody>\n";
                                echo "</table><br>\n";

                            ?>
                        </article>


                        <article class="content__item">
                            <h3 class="title title--fullo"> <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Report: Business Criticality</h3>
                            <div style="background: #999; color: white; font-weight: normal; padding: 10px; width: 100%">
                                Ricerca <input type="text" id="filterboxE">
                            </div>
                            <?php
                                echo "<table id=\"BC\" class=\"display\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"100%\">";
                                echo "<thead>";
                                echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<th>Apparato </th>\n";
                                echo "<th>BC </th>\n";
                                echo "<th>Servizio </th>\n";
                                echo "<th>Dominio </th>\n";
                                echo "<th>Indirizzo IP </th>\n";
                                echo "<th>SO </th>\n";
                                echo "<th>Assegnato a </th>\n";
                                echo "<th>Tipo </th>\n";
                                echo "<th>CED </th>\n";
                                echo "<th>Stato </th>\n";
                                echo "<th>Ambiente </th>\n";
                                echo "</tr>";
                                echo "</thead>";
                                echo "</table><br>";
                            ?>
                        </article>

                        <article class="content__item">
                            <h3 class="title title--fullo"> <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Report: Elenco Servizi / Apparati</h3>
                            <div style="background: #999; color: white; font-weight: normal; padding: 10px; width: 100%">
                                Ricerca <input type="text" id="filterboxF">
                                <a style="color: white" href="javascript:exportREPORTS2('PCMDB_CAT.REPORTS')"><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Esporta Tutto</a>
                                <a id="partialExport" style="color: white" onclick="var limiter = 0; var arrProva =[]; var arrFinal = []; var count = 0; var countTableRows = tableSA.rows( { search: 'applied' } ).count(); tableSA.rows( { search:'applied' } ).data().each(function(value, index) {

                                         arrProva = [value];

                                         count++;

                                         $.ajax({
                                                type:'POST',
                                                url:'exportREPORTS_SA_Filtered.php',
                                                data: { ok: 1, arrayFiltrato: arrProva, countRows: countTableRows },
                                                success: function(msg) {

                                                        $('#downloadPartialExport').html('Download Export Parziale');
                                                        $('#downloadPartialExport').attr('href',msg);
                                                        $('#downloadPartialExport').css('display','inline-block');

                                                },
                                                error: function(err) {
                                                    alert('Errore ' + err);
                                                }
                                              });

                                     });"><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Esporta Parziale</a>
                                     <a style="color:white; font-weight: bold;" id="downloadPartialExport" href=""></a>
                                                                    </div>
                            <?php
                                echo "<table id=\"SA\" class=\"display\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"100%\">";
                                echo "<thead>";
                                echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<th>SERVIZIO</th>\n";
                                echo "<th>APPARATO</th>\n";
                                echo "<th>Ambiente </th>\n";
                                echo "<th>Indirizzo IP </th>\n";
                                echo "<th>Dominio </th>\n";
                                echo "<th>Sistema Operativo </th>\n";
                                echo "<th>Service Pack</th>";
                                echo "<th>Tipo </th>\n";
                                echo "<th>CED </th>\n";
                                echo "<th>ID Config </th>\n";
                                echo "<th>Operation </th>\n";
                                echo "</tr>";
                                echo "</thead>";
                                echo "</table><br>";
                            ?>
                        </article>

                        <article class="content__item">
                            <div class="modal fade" id="contextMenuIdConfApparati" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                              <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Numero di Apparati</h5>
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-body">
                                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                                        <ul id="resultApparatiList" class="list-group list-group-flush"><!-- list-group e list-group-flush consentono di definire e stilizzare una lista di item -->
                            </ul>
                                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="document.getElementById('contextMenuIdConfApparati').style.display = 'none';">Close</button>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                            <h3 class="title title--fullo"> <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Report: Elenco Sistemi Operativi inclusi in un Servizio</h3>
                            <div style="background: #999; color: white; font-weight: normal; padding: 10px; width: 100%">
                                Ricerca <input type="text" id="filterboxG">
                                <a style="color: white" href="javascript:exportREPORTS3('PCMDB_CAT.REPORTS')"><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Esporta Tutto</a>
                                <a id="partialExport2" style="color: white" onclick="var limiter = 0; var arrFinal = {}; var count = 0; var countTableRows = tableSO.rows( { search: 'applied' } ).count(); tableSO.rows( { search:'applied' } ).data().each(function() {

                                         arrFinal = tableSO.rows( { search:'applied' } ).data();

                                         count++;

                                     });

                                     $.ajax({
                                            type:'POST',
                                            url:'exportREPORTS_SO_filtered.php',
                                            data: { ok: 1, arrayFiltrato: JSON.stringify(arrFinal), countRows: countTableRows },
                                            success: function(msg) {

                                                    $('#downloadPartialExport2').html('Download Export Parziale');
                                                    $('#downloadPartialExport2').attr('href',msg);
                                                    $('#downloadPartialExport2').css('display','inline-block');

                                            },
                                            error: function(err) {
                                                alert('Errore ' + err);
                                            }
                                            });"><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Esporta Parziale</a>
                                     <a style="color:white; font-weight: bold;" id="downloadPartialExport2" href=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                                echo "<table id=\"SO\" class=\"display\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"100%\">";
                                echo "</table><br />";
                            ?>
                            <button class="close-button"><i class="fa fa-close"></i><span>Close</span></button>
                        </article>

                        <article class="content__item">
                            <h3 class="title title--fullo"> <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Report: Vista Tripletta</h3>
                            <div style="background: #999; color: white; font-weight: normal; padding: 10px; width: 100%">
                                Ricerca stringa <input type="text" id="paramic" name="paramic"> <input type="button" value="Trova" onclick="vistaCompletaTripletta()">
                            </div>

                            <?php
                                echo "<table id=\"TRIPLETTA\" class=\"display\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"100%\">";
                                echo "<thead>";
                                echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<th>Servizio</th><th>Sottoservizio</th><th>Funzione</th>";
                            ?>

                            <script>

                            function vistaCompletaTripletta(){

                                var paramic = $("#paramic").val();

                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "GET",
                                    url: "tripletta.php",
                                    data: {
                                        "param": paramic
                                    },
                                    success: function(chicco){
                                        $("#TRIPLETTA").html(chicco);
                                    },
                                });

                                //$('#TRIPLETTA').dataTable().fnDestroy();

                                var table = $('#TRIPLETTA').DataTable( {
                                    "paging": false,
                                    "bFilter": false,
                                    "processing": true,
                                    "serverSide": false,
                                    "deferLoading": 57,
                                    "deferRender": true,
                                    "scrollY": 300,
                                    "scrollX": true,
                                    "bPaginate": false,
                                    "info": false,
                                    "bRetrieve": true
                                });

                            }
                            </script>

                        </article>

                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /container -->
        <script src="js/classie.js"></script>
        <script src="js/json2.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Too much code, nobody will read all that. Narrow down the problem scope. A possibility since you mention images loading is that you don't have enough concurrent connections available, so look at upping that.

Comment: A good start when a page loads slowly is to try and work out which part is slow.  Remove the code which is purely HTML and narrow it down from there.

Comment: I know you are right but actually I don't know where to speed up the code.

Comment: @NigelRen so you think that it could be better creating the html with php rather than standard html? for istance, is better writing: echo "<div>bla bla bla</div>"; rather than putting the html in the same page?

Comment: @MyNameIs yes I know I am sorry but I am very worried so I am focused on the problem and not on the words '-.-

Comment: No - I just mean to remove any code which isn't a performance problem - till you find the problem

Comment: Ok I will double check it. Thank you Nigel ;)

Comment: Hi @EmilioAlfieri, It could be your SQL requests slowing you down, try adding some indexes to the correct rows of the tables. Just looking at what you are currently filtering off, or doing your SELECT statements from... maybe these fields need indexes.  ambiente, id_servizio, NOME_SERVIZIO, STATUS

Comment: @vr_driver I will look into SQL requests too! Many thanks! ;D

Comment: you are leaking mail and phone number though, probably of a colleague of yours. And your employer too

Comment: @AndreaGolin That’s me :)

Comment: Well, that mail looks like it belongs to the file author, your name is listed as reviewer. But hey, you know better than me for sure

Comment: @AndreaGolin Yes you should be right but he doesn't work here anymore so I just trying to refactoring his code '-.-  anyway I followed your suggestion, much better ;)